# Delete rows from table inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a problem, I explain:

I have a table called **Tipo_Base** that contains Id, nombre_tipo_base

I have a table called **Tipo_Base_Lista** that contains Id, id_tipo_base, and lista_id

I have a table called **Modelo_unidad** that contains Id, nombre_modelo and id_tipo_base

I have a table called **Modelo_Lista** that contains Id, id_modelo, id_lista

Each **id_lista** of the table **modelo_lista** MUST be present in the table **tipo_base_lista**, then, when I delete a **id_lista** from the table **tipo_base_lista**, it must also be deleted from the table **modelo_lista**.

Try the following:

```
DELETE Tbl_modelo_lista
    FROM 
        Tbl_modelo_lista 
        INNER JOIN Tbl_modelo_unidad as MU ON MU.id_modelo = Tbl_modelo_lista.id_modelo
        INNER JOIN Tbl_tipo_base_lista as TBL ON TBL.id_tipo_base = MU.id_tipo_base
    WHERE
        TBL.id_lista <> Tbl_modelo_lista.id_lista
```

Comment: One good way to implement this behavior would be to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` such that deleting a row from `tipo_base_lista` also deletes the corresponding records in `modelo_lista`.  If you _can't_ do this, then you will probably have to use two separate `DELETE` statements.  AFAIK it's not possible to delete from more than one table in SQL Server, in a single statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logic you want is more like this:

```
DELETE ml
    FROM Tbl_modelo_lista ml INNER JOIN
         Tbl_modelo_unidad mu
         ON mu.id_modelo = ml.id_modelo LEFT JOIN
         Tbl_tipo_base_lista tbl
         ON tbl.id_tipo_base = mu.id_tipo_base AND
            tbl.id_lista = ml.id_lista
    WHERE tbl.id_lista IS NULL;
```

Normally, the way to implement this logic is with a cascading delete constraint.  In your case, I'm not sure this would work.  Cascading triggers are useful when you need to propagate changes from the reference table outwards.  They don't keep track of incoming references and delete a record when there are no references.